# Add JS to head in Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, blocks, head

I have a problem when I want to put JS into my head when the PHP condition is met, but I'm getting Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type exception no idea why. I have read all the possible issues I have found but looks like there is a ton of places I could go wrong and right now I'm out of ideas.

I have config.xml where is my module declared. This is only part of it as the rest of the module is working, also JS and CSS I have in module_name.xml are working properly.

```
</frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <module_name>
                <file>module_name.xml</file>
            </module_name>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then I have module_name.xml I understand that I say here "on checkout/cart page load this template/module name/prepended.phtml into  of page.

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="namespace_moduleName/cart" name="prependca" template="modulename/prependca.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Last, but not least, I have this Class of mine:

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract {

    public function prependCa() {
        $_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if (get_class($_quote) == Mage_Sales_Model_Quote) {
            $head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
            $head->addJs('namespace/modulenameTotals.js');
            $head->addItem('js', 'namespace/modulenameTotals.js');
        }
    }
}
```

From what I have read, I did all I had to do, however, I still don't get results, and only response I get is Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type

Comment: did you try using `core/template` block?

Comment: tried now, surprisingly still same...

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this :

   ```
   <checkout_cart_index>
       <reference name="head">
           <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/my-custom.js</name></action>
       </reference>
   </checkout_cart_index>
   ```
2. Create your new **js** file in: `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/my-custom.js` then put your code inside.
3. Now your **js** file will be just loaded in **checkout/cart**. *Don't forget to clear the cache*.

---

**NB:** I see some errors in your code:

**1)**

```
<frontend> // not </frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <module_name>
                <file>module_name.xml</file>
            </module_name>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

**2)**

You can't load this type of block in a **head** ! but you can do it `content`, `root` etc...

If you need is to add a js file, follow my solution.

Comment: i tried changing from head to content or root, but still doesnt work. My main problem is that I cant use theme...

Comment: What kind of block do you want to add ?, it's a Js file ?